# How do you use a keyboard with a first-generation Apple TV?

Tags: keyboard, usb, appletv

How do you configure a first-generation Apple TV to use a keyboard connected via USB?

Comment: A keyboard requires tvOS 5.2 I think.  Can the first generation handle that?  Otherwise you may be able to use the Remote app on an iPhone/iPad.